# OS X: How to change file name from time stamp

Tags: macos

I would like to know how to change file name using the time stamp but keep the initial name of the file.

**Reason:**
Time stamp of my file has been changed by microwave so I would like to keep the time and date into file name.

**For example:**

Initial file name

```
CAFE_FINDER_.txt                 2014-04-18 01:09:37
```

New file name

```
CAFE_FINDER_20140418_010937.txt  2014-04-18 01:09:37
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Terminal you can change the file name like this:

```
cd "path/to/the/folder"
old_filename="CAFE_FINDER_.txt"
new_filename=${old_filename%.*}$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").${old_filename##*.}
mv "$old_filename" "$new_filename"
```

If you want to use the creation date of the file instead of the current date, change the line to

```
new_filename=${old_filename%.*}$(stat -f %SB -t "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S" "$old_filename").${old_filename##*.}
```

In Applescript:

```
do shell script 
"file='path/to/the/folder/CAFE_FINDER_.txt'
old_filename=$(basename \"$file\")
new_filename=${old_filename%.*}$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S').${old_filename##*.}
#for current date
#for creation date of the file:
#new_filename=${old_filename%.*}$(stat -f %SB -t '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S' \"$file\").${old_filename##*.}
mv \"$file\" \"$(dirname \"$file\")/$new_filename\"
"
```

I would prefer Applescript to build a [droplet](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24772).

Answer (score 0):

There is an App called [A Better Finder Rename](http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/) that is able to do that (besides lots of other renaming possibilities). You can select between the files creation and modification date as well as todays date and even an exif-date that might exist in the file. You are able to either rename the file using the date time or append or prepend the date to the current filename.

Only drawback of the test-version is that you can only rename 10 files in a go. Depending on the number of files it might be worth investing the around 20$

Comment: Why not check and see whether it actually is able to do that to make this an actual answer? :-)

Answer (score -1):

I work with this script which can use some improvement:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$1" || exit
for i in * ; do
  new=$(stat -c %y "$i"|awk '{print $1"_"$2}'|cut -f1 -d'.'|tr ':' '-')_$i
  mv "$i" "$new"
done
echo "finished!"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).